# How do I find out my Facebook page ID?

Tags: wordpress, facebook-page

I've tried using `findmyfacebookid.com` but it comes back with:

```
Unable to lookup Facebook numeric ID. You can try again, or see this tutorial for an alternate method.
```

I also tried the alternate method with no luck. Any ideas how to get the Facebook identifier for a page?

The page is `www.facebook.com/mickandsheilagillmortgageexperts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the link `http://graph.facebook.com/username` will effectively return a JSON array of `username`'s details.

Use the field `id` to get a user's page identifier. Here's an example using [Zuckerberg's profile](http://graph.facebook.com/zuck).

```
{
   "id": "4",
   "name": "Mark Zuckerberg",
   "first_name": "Mark",
   "last_name": "Zuckerberg",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/zuck",
   "username": "zuck",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

Comment: That means the user doesn't exist and/or that input isn't valid.

Comment: It has to exist. The page is www.facebook.com/mickandsheilagillmortgageexperts

Comment: Not sure why that would be - probably the same reason why the apps you tried using didn't work. That page's ID is `180883565329613`, but I don't have a definite method of retrieving it. Putting `180883565329613` into graph search shows the same error, so it might be a setting on that page.